# InvalidOrMissingInputException when calling gestream API

Tags: getstream-io

When ever I try to call getstream API using the below method for saving an activity (JSON) I get following exception. This exception occurs occasionally. How do we solve this?

***JSON*** : (activityTask)

```
{
    "processingType": "PERSIST_AND_NOTIFY",
    "carbookBaseActivity": {
        "actor": "7d8d59d1-1997-4213-81c0-32de463466f6",
        "verb": "favorite",
        "object": "{\"city\":\"Weimar\",\"postcode\":\"99423\",\"street\":\" Ernst-Thälmann-Straße\",\"housenumber\":\"\",\"countrycode\":\"DE\",\"county\":\"\",\"suburb\":\"\",\"state\":\"\",\"geopoint\":{\"lon\":11.3224816,\"lat\":50.9887822,\"alt\":0.0}}",
        "target": "NA",
        "time": "2017-04-17T08:43:09.527",
        "to": [],
        "acted": false,
        "timeToLive": 1492591389527,
        "userClusterId": "f7e3e39e-22a3-48c5-a043-f439e23b9bb2",
        "label": "OFFICE",
        "pictureUrl": "NA",
        "status": 0,
        "addressType": "OFFICE",
        "foreign_id": "8ad1b071-e45d-4993-b077-ca843f137322",
        "carbookBaseType": "TASK"
    }
}
```

***Method*** :

`CarbookBaseActivity response = flatActivityService.addActivity(activityTask);`

***Exception*** :

```
io.getstream.client.exception.InvalidOrMissingInputException
    at io.getstream.client.apache.repo.handlers.StreamExceptionHandler.handleResponseCode(StreamExceptionHandler.java:73) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at io.getstream.client.apache.repo.StreamActivityRepository.handleResponseCode(StreamActivityRepository.java:266) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at io.getstream.client.apache.repo.StreamActivityRepository.addActivity(StreamActivityRepository.java:103) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at io.getstream.client.apache.repo.StreamRepositoryImpl.addActivity(StreamRepositoryImpl.java:199) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at io.getstream.client.service.AbstractActivityService.addActivity(AbstractActivityService.java:69) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at de.carbook.storm.activity.operation.ActivityOperation.handleLocationPredicitionTask(ActivityOperation.java:230) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at de.carbook.storm.activity.operation.ActivityOperation.handleCarbookBaseActivity(ActivityOperation.java:115) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at de.carbook.storm.activity.operation.ActivityOperation.handleActivity(ActivityOperation.java:73) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at de.carbook.storm.activity.extract.ActivityBolt.execute(ActivityBolt.java:89) [stormjar.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.topology.BasicBoltExecutor.execute(BasicBoltExecutor.java:50) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4273$tuple_action_fn__4275.invoke(executor.clj:670) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__4196.invoke(executor.clj:426) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__3772.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:125) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4273$fn__4286$fn__4337.invoke(executor.clj:808) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__543.invoke(util.clj:475) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
2017-04-17 14:41:10.461 b.s.d.executor [ERROR] 
io.getstream.client.exception.InvalidOrMissingInputException
    at io.getstream.client.apache.repo.handlers.StreamExceptionHandler.handleResponseCode(StreamExceptionHandler.java:73) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at io.getstream.client.apache.repo.StreamActivityRepository.handleResponseCode(StreamActivityRepository.java:266) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at io.getstream.client.apache.repo.StreamActivityRepository.addActivity(StreamActivityRepository.java:103) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at io.getstream.client.apache.repo.StreamRepositoryImpl.addActivity(StreamRepositoryImpl.java:199) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at io.getstream.client.service.AbstractActivityService.addActivity(AbstractActivityService.java:69) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at de.carbook.storm.activity.operation.ActivityOperation.handleLocationPredicitionTask(ActivityOperation.java:230) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at de.carbook.storm.activity.operation.ActivityOperation.handleCarbookBaseActivity(ActivityOperation.java:115) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at de.carbook.storm.activity.operation.ActivityOperation.handleActivity(ActivityOperation.java:73) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at de.carbook.storm.activity.extract.ActivityBolt.execute(ActivityBolt.java:89) [stormjar.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.topology.BasicBoltExecutor.execute(BasicBoltExecutor.java:50) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4273$tuple_action_fn__4275.invoke(executor.clj:670) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__4196.invoke(executor.clj:426) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__3772.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:125) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4273$fn__4286$fn__4337.invoke(executor.clj:808) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__543.invoke(util.clj:475) [storm-core-0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485.jar:0.10.0.2.3.4.0-3485]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
```

***Response*** :

```
InvalidOrMissingInputException
{statusCode=400, code=4, exception=InputException, detail=Errors for fields 'object'}
```

Comment: did you already look at the response body when you receive a 4xx error? There should be a JSON encoded message with some information about what is not valid in the activity payload

Comment: I tried re sending the same JSON, in reply I got **_Response_**

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli the object I send is a json string.

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli For some JSON String it passes for some it throws ecxception (like the above one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value used in actor, object and verb fields must be ASCII encoded, in your example I see you are sending non ASCII char such as `ß` and `ä`. I am surprised you don't see a clear validation error about this in the response body, I suggest you open an issue on the Github repo for the API client you are using or reach to Stream support directly.

Slightly out of topic: I see that you are storing fairly complex data inside your activities. While this is supported by the APIs, the general recommendation is to only keep references to data. Doing so makes it easier to update the data inside activities.

For example: Lat/Long will never change, but the way you represent them probably will.

Comment: Sure will raise the ticket. And about the complexities of activity data, we are developing permalink's for most of our data, thereby we can reduce such issues. Thanks for your help and info.